# Reinstall anonsurf GUI on parrot

Tags: linux, gui, apt, parrot-os

I deleted anonsurf gui thats installed by default on my parrot os.

I saw many articles on how to install it on kali but none on parrot.

Please help.

Comment: How did you delete it?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek it got removed when i removed a python version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`anonsurf` can be installed through apt. You should have the following lines in your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/parrot.list`:

```
deb https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot/ rolling main contrib non-free
deb https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot/ rolling-security main contrib non-free
```

Then

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install anonsurf-gtk
```

Comment: This is not the GUI that comes by default this is a different version. I did install this but my question is about the GUI version and not this

Comment: @JaysmitoMukherjee See my update.

Comment: thanks! it worked